# Importing modules from parent directory in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, pytest

I'm failing to import a module from a parent directory in 2.7 and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

### Directory Structure

I have a Python package with this directory structure:

```
source/
|--foo/__init__.py
|--foo/bar/__init__.py
|--foo/bar/nested.py
|--foo/top.py
tests/
|--helpers/__init__.py
|--foo/__init__.py
|--foo/bar/__init__.py
|--foo/bar/nested_test.py
|--foo/top_test.py
setup.py
setup.cfg
tox.ini
```

### Configuration

I use `pytest` and `python setup.py test` almost interchangeably to run my tests with. In `tox.ini`, I have:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv]
commands = pytest
deps = pytest

[pytest]
testpaths=tests
```

Note, that I don't actually use `tox` to run my tests.

And in `setup.cfg`:

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this setup means that when I run `python setup.py test`, it actually just runs `pytest`, so it *might* not be relevant to this question.

### Question

In `foo/top_test.py`, I can `import tests.helpers`, but in `foo/bar/nested_test.py`, the same import raises an `ImportError` saying that the module was not found.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

### Attempts

I've attempted to run `pytest` and `python setup.py test` in a clean virtualenv after running `pip install pytest` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` (My `requirements.txt` is basically a blank file with `-e` and `-i` set to a private repo.

Note: I can open up a `python` REPL from the root directory of the project and `import tests._helper` without any problems.

I've also attempted to add `tests` and `tests.helpers` to the `tests_require` argument in the `setuptools.setup()` function in `setup.py`, but it looks like it attempts to install those from the remote index instead of using the local modules.

I've also attempted appending to `sys.path` in my foo/bar/nested_test.py:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('tests'))
```

### Other notes

- I'm not willing to bundle my tests into the source directory into each package
- I'm unable to use python 3 at the moment

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is you don't appear to have a `tests/__init__.py`.  Not sure if that matters in your case but it does in the example below.

Whenever I have a problem like this I try and setup a simplified test case with as few things as possible.  Get setuptools, pytest and all that other noise out of the way and just debug the module structure and then add those back after you know your structure is sound.

For example, here's a script

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf tests
mkdir -p tests/foo/bar
mkdir -p tests/helpers
touch tests/__init__.py
touch tests/foo/__init__.py
touch tests/foo/bar/__init__.py
touch tests/helpers/__init__.py
echo 'import tests.helpers' > tests/foo/top_test.py
echo 'import tests.helpers' > tests/foo/bar/nested_test.py
tree tests
python -c 'import tests.foo.bar.nested_test; print "got here"'
```

which produces the output

```
tests
|-- __init__.py
|-- foo
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- bar
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- nested_test.py
|   `-- top_test.py
`-- helpers
    `-- __init__.py

3 directories, 6 files
got here
```

Once you have a simple script like this you can interactively experiment with your imports.